# Printing Function Address

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

I've been trying a way to figure out how to print the address of the function, This is what I came up with

```
#include<stdio.h>
int test(int a, int b)
{
     return a+b;
}
int main(void)
{
     int (*ptr)(int,int);
     ptr=&test;
     printf("The address of the function is =%p\n",ptr);
     printf("The address of the function pointer is =%p\n",&ptr);
     return 0;
}
```

It o/p something like this without any warning and errors

```
address of function is =0x4006fa
address of function pointer  is =0x7fffae4f73d8
```

My question whether using **%p** format specifier  is the correct way to print the address of the function or is there any other way to do so?

Comment: The name of the function is the address of it. You can achieve the same result by using:

`printf ("Address of function: %p\n", test);`

And yes: %p is the correct format specifier to print pointer values (memory addresses) because the implementation knows how your pointers look like.

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix: That's is incorrect. `%p` can be used with `void *` pointers and (after conversion) with other object pointers. `%p` cannot be used with function pointers.

Comment: I've just tested it on Linux and gcc. Compiling with -Wall doesn't trigger any warnings, and it prints the actual address of main

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not correct. `%p` is only for object pointer types (in fact, `void *` specifically).  There is no format specifier for a function pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Without using the separate pointer for print the address of the function, You can use the name of the function in the `printf`.

```
 printf("The address of the function is =%p\n",test);
```

For printing the address in the hexa-decimal format you can use the `%p`.

Comment: This fails when compiling with `-pedantic-errors`, with the message `format specifies type 'void *' but the argument has type 'void (*)()'`